# Network error while using jquery in Django 

Tags: jquery, django

"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://192.168.0.116:8000/maps/django/contrib/admin/media/js/jquery.js"

This is the error that I get when I start up my page.As per the tutorials the jquery.js is stored in media . So where is the problem?

Comment: is you MEDIA_URL /media/? if so get rid of maps/django/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 0):

django does not serve the admin media when `settings.DEBUG` is `False`.

You have to do it yourself: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/